# jQuery REplace Fade Effect with slide up /Slide Down

Tags: jquery, fade, slideup

Can anyone help me to rewrite the below code which use a fade effect , to use a sliding effect.I want Slide up and Slide Down

```
 function ShowCostMetrics()
 {
  $("#pnlGraph").fadeOut("slow",function()
   {
    $("#pnlCostMetrics").fadeIn("slow");
   });
 }
 function ShowGraph()
 {
   $("#pnlCostMetrics").fadeOut("slow",function()
   {
     $("#pnlGraph").fadeIn("slow");
    });
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of **fadeIn/Out** use **slideDown/Up**

```
 function ShowCostMetrics()
 {
  $("#pnlGraph").slideUp("slow",function()
   {
    $("#pnlCostMetrics").slideDown("slow");
   });
 }
 function ShowGraph()
 {
   $("#pnlCostMetrics").slideUp("slow",function()
   {
     $("#pnlGraph").slideDown("slow");
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could simply switch all `fadeIn()` with `slideDown()` and `fadeOut()` with `slideUp()`...